# Azure devops test plans reports - how to display test case run date

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Currently using the built in report charts and progress report in azure test plans to display our teams test metrics.

Is there a way to include the last time a test was run in either the test chart or the progress report?

Foe example a failed test only shows up as a failed test point in the chart. In order to trace when it was last run you have to double click on the test suite containing the failed test in the progress report, this opens up a display with each of the test points where you then have to select the 'Execute' tab in order to see which tests are marked as failed. you then have to click into the test point in order to see the test case results which contains the timestamp for when it was run.

Is there a way to include the timestamp for the last time the test case or test suite containing the failed test case was run within one of the report charts?

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I will look to see if there are any alternative solutions to so this

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no such option can include the timestamp for the last run time of the test case or test suite in test Charts or Progress Report for the time being.

Currently, the test chars and progress report supports showing the number of tests and test result count statistics.

It doesn't have no column or field to display timestamp.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report this feature.